# Checkout shipping fields different than default

Tags: magento-2.1, onestepcheckout

I am developing a Magento 2.1.6 store, with data migrated from Magento 1.9.3.
Is there something in the database that could cause my checkout shipping page to not display all the relevant form fields?

Looking at a demo store online, it seems that the default fields on checkout should include the following:

Email

First Name

Last Name

Company

Street Address (x2)

City

State/Province

Zip/Postcode

Country

Phone

**But my page is missing several of these, and only includes:**

Email

Company

City

Zip/Postcode

Phone

Fax

I have not made any changes to `checkout_index_index.xml`, and the `theme (Ultimo)` only modifies the header and footer layout blocks.

This leaves me thinking that something in the database might be causing the issue, from the migrated data.

What can I look for in the database (maybe?) that might also impact this?

If it isn't something in the database, then how can I find out if any files are instructing the system to remove fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be a problem with EAV attributes in the database. The company that migrated the data from my 1.9 store resolved it for me.